# How to get the nickname of the author of the message in the discord using Discord.net 2.2.0 C#

Tags: c#, discord.net

How can I get the nickname of the author of the message in Discord using Discord.net 2.2.0.

```
private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(SocketMessage message)
{
    if (StartBit == 0)
    { 
    await message.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Test");
    }
    StartBit = 1;
    // The bot should never respond to itself.
    if (message.Author.Id == _client.CurrentUser.Id)
        return;
    var UName = message.Author.Username;
    var UID = message.Author.Id;
}
```

A long search and reading of the documentation unfortunately gave me nothing.

Comment: You need to cast the `message.Author` as a `SocketGuildUser`. By default the `Author` will be a `SocketUser` which only has `Username` and not `Nickname` because nicknames are only valid within a `Guild` context. As messages can also be sent via Direct Message, the `SocketUser` variant is used. Basically, if safe casting the `Author` to a `SocketGuildUser` returns `null` then the message was sent via DM. If the cast is successful, you will not have access to the `Guild` and the `Nickname`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get the authors nick name you can cast it to SocketGuildUser, **but beware, it can be null if it's a DM**.

```cs
var UNick = (message.Author as SocketGuildUser).Nickname;
```

Also you probably should check if the message is from a user and not system

```cs
if (!(sockMessage is SocketUserMessage msg))
    return;
```

So your code will look something like this

```cs
private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(SocketMessage sockMessage) 
{ 
    // Check if a user posted the message
    if (!(sockMessage is SocketUserMessage msg))
        return;

    // Check if it is not a DM
    if (!(msg.Author as SocketGuildUser author))
        return;

    if (StartBit == 0) 
    { 
        await msg.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Test");
    }

    StartBit = 1; 

    // I usualy check if the author is not bot, but you can change that back
    if (msg.Author.IsBot) 
        return; 

    var UName = author.Username; 
    var UNick = author.Nickname;
    var UID = author.Id;
}
```

Credit to [*Anu6is*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11159372/anu6is)

Comment: You are using `message` in your example, but you don't have it defined anywhere. Did you maybe intent to use `msg` or `sockMessage`?

Comment: this was posted years ago so i dont know the original context, but from what i can see, you are right. it should be msg

Answer (score 0):

Try casting your message to an SocketUserMessage. I have attached the correct code for that and please edit your post, so that the code is presented correctly.

```
private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(SocketMessage msg) 
{ 
    SocketUserMessage message = msg as SocketUserMessage;

    if (StartBit == 0) 
    { 
        await message.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Test");
    } 
    StartBit = 1; 

    // The bot should never respond to itself.
    if (message.Author.Id == _client.CurrentUser.Id) return; 

    var UName = message.Author.Username; 
    var UID = message.Author.Id;
```

}

Comment: Sorry for the incorrectly written message, I am writing for the first time. And I still have not figured out how to edit the message here.